# Build multiple images vs start multiple containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What's the best practices?

- Build different docker images for each application instance. For example, each application instance has its own code directory. Use ADD to build different images
- Build a base image. Start a new container for each application instance. Use option -v to bind specific volume for each application instance.

Reasons go for multiple containers:

- Using ADD in Dockerfile means you need rebuild your image once any changes in that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if best practice but i'd go for the -v option just for the numbers: you have to create a container for every code directory anyway, i would avoid having to build the same number of images too.
Moreover disk space may be an issue but im not sure

one image and one container for every code directory < one image and multiple associated container with different mount point for every code directory